# Conda environment lags/hangs during installation of packages

Tags: python, package, conda, environment, lag

I have been having issues with Conda package installation. Unlike others' issues where Conda lags around solving sources, my Conda always lags after installing all the necessary software (or so I think). Here's an example as of late:

```
(DGE_smk_minimal) [name@server DGE-co-culture-workflow]$ conda install snakemake
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/kve/.conda/envs/DGE_smk_minimal:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    aioeasywebdav:                 2.4.0-py39hf3d152e_1001    conda-forge
    aiohttp:                       3.7.4.post0-py39h3811e60_0 conda-forge
    amply:                         0.1.4-py_0                 conda-forge
    appdirs:                       1.4.4-pyh9f0ad1d_0         conda-forge
    async-timeout:                 3.0.1-py_1000              conda-forge
    atk-1.0:                       2.36.0-h3371d22_4          conda-forge
    attmap:                        0.13.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    attrs:                         21.2.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    backports:                     1.0-py_2                   conda-forge
    backports.functools_lru_cache: 1.6.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    bcrypt:                        3.2.0-py39h3811e60_1       conda-forge
    boto3:                         1.18.26-pyhd8ed1ab_0       conda-forge
    botocore:                      1.21.26-pyhd8ed1ab_0       conda-forge
    brotlipy:                      0.7.0-py39h38d8fee_1001    conda-forge
    cachetools:                    4.2.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    cairo:                         1.16.0-h6cf1ce9_1008       conda-forge
    certifi:                       2021.5.30-py39hf3d152e_0   conda-forge
    cffi:                          1.14.6-py39he32792d_0      conda-forge
    chardet:                       4.0.0-py39hf3d152e_1       conda-forge
    charset-normalizer:            2.0.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    coincbc:                       2.10.5-hcee13e7_1          conda-forge
    configargparse:                1.5.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    connection_pool:               0.0.3-pyhd3deb0d_0         conda-forge
    cryptography:                  3.4.7-py39hbca0aa6_0       conda-forge
    datrie:                        0.8.2-py39h3811e60_2       conda-forge
    decorator:                     5.0.9-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    docutils:                      0.17.1-py39hf3d152e_0      conda-forge
    dropbox:                       10.9.0-pyhd3deb0d_0        conda-forge
    filechunkio:                   1.8-py_2                   conda-forge
    filelock:                      3.0.12-pyh9f0ad1d_0        conda-forge
    fontconfig:                    2.13.1-hba837de_1005       conda-forge
    freetype:                      2.10.4-h0708190_1          conda-forge
    ftputil:                       5.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    gdk-pixbuf:                    2.42.6-h04a7f16_0          conda-forge
    gitdb:                         4.0.7-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    gitpython:                     3.1.18-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    google-api-core:               1.31.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    google-api-python-client:      2.17.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    google-auth:                   1.35.0-pyh6c4a22f_0        conda-forge
    google-auth-httplib2:          0.1.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    google-cloud-core:             1.7.2-pyh6c4a22f_0         conda-forge
    google-cloud-storage:          1.42.0-pyh6c4a22f_0        conda-forge
    google-crc32c:                 1.1.2-py39hb81f231_0       conda-forge
    google-resumable-media:        1.3.3-pyh6c4a22f_0         conda-forge
    googleapis-common-protos:      1.53.0-py39hf3d152e_0      conda-forge
    graphviz:                      2.48.0-h85b4f2f_0          conda-forge
    grpcio:                        1.38.1-py39hff7568b_0      conda-forge
    gtk2:                          2.24.33-h539f30e_1         conda-forge
    gts:                           0.7.6-h64030ff_2           conda-forge
    harfbuzz:                      2.9.0-h83ec7ef_0           conda-forge
    httplib2:                      0.19.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    idna:                          3.1-pyhd3deb0d_0           conda-forge
    imagemagick:                   7.1.0_5-pl5321hb118871_0   conda-forge
    importlib-metadata:            4.6.4-py39hf3d152e_0       conda-forge
    iniconfig:                     1.1.1-pyh9f0ad1d_0         conda-forge
    ipython_genutils:              0.2.0-py_1                 conda-forge
    jinja2:                        3.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    jmespath:                      0.10.0-pyh9f0ad1d_0        conda-forge
    jsonschema:                    3.2.0-pyhd8ed1ab_3         conda-forge
    jupyter_core:                  4.7.1-py39hf3d152e_0       conda-forge
    libblas:                       3.9.0-11_linux64_openblas  conda-forge
    libcblas:                      3.9.0-11_linux64_openblas  conda-forge
    libgd:                         2.3.2-h78a0170_0           conda-forge
    libglib:                       2.68.4-h3e27bee_0          conda-forge
    liblapack:                     3.9.0-11_linux64_openblas  conda-forge
    libpng:                        1.6.37-hed695b0_2          conda-forge
    libprotobuf:                   3.17.2-h780b84a_1          conda-forge
    librsvg:                       2.50.7-hc3c00ef_0          conda-forge
    libtiff:                       4.3.0-hf544144_1           conda-forge
    libwebp:                       1.2.1-h3452ae3_0           conda-forge
    libxcb:                        1.13-h7f98852_1003         conda-forge
    libxml2:                       2.9.12-h72842e0_0          conda-forge
    logmuse:                       0.2.6-pyh8c360ce_0         conda-forge
    markupsafe:                    2.0.1-py39h3811e60_0       conda-forge
    more-itertools:                8.8.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    multidict:                     5.1.0-py39h3811e60_1       conda-forge
    nbformat:                      5.1.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    networkx:                      2.5-py_0                   conda-forge
    numpy:                         1.21.2-py39hdbf815f_0      conda-forge
    oauth2client:                  4.1.3-py_0                 conda-forge
    openjpeg:                      2.4.0-hb52868f_1           conda-forge
    packaging:                     21.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0          conda-forge
    pandas:                        1.3.2-py39hde0f152_0       conda-forge
    pango:                         1.48.9-hb8ff022_0          conda-forge
    paramiko:                      2.7.2-pyh9f0ad1d_0         conda-forge
    peppy:                         0.31.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    pip:                           21.2.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    pluggy:                        0.13.1-py39hf3d152e_4      conda-forge
    prettytable:                   2.1.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    protobuf:                      3.17.2-py39he80948d_0      conda-forge
    psutil:                        5.8.0-py39h3811e60_1       conda-forge
    pulp:                          2.5.0-py39hf3d152e_0       conda-forge
    py:                            1.10.0-pyhd3deb0d_0        conda-forge
    pyasn1:                        0.4.8-py_0                 conda-forge
    pyasn1-modules:                0.2.7-py_0                 conda-forge
    pycparser:                     2.20-pyh9f0ad1d_2          conda-forge
    pygments:                      2.10.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    pygraphviz:                    1.7-py39h78163bd_0         conda-forge
    pynacl:                        1.4.0-py39h3811e60_2       conda-forge
    pyopenssl:                     20.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    pyparsing:                     2.4.7-pyh9f0ad1d_0         conda-forge
    pyrsistent:                    0.17.3-py39h3811e60_2      conda-forge
    pysftp:                        0.2.9-py_1                 conda-forge
    pysocks:                       1.7.1-py39hf3d152e_3       conda-forge
    pytest:                        6.2.4-py39hf3d152e_0       conda-forge
    python:                        3.9.6-h49503c6_1_cpython   conda-forge
    python-dateutil:               2.8.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    python-irodsclient:            1.0.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    python_abi:                    3.9-2_cp39                 conda-forge
    pytz:                          2021.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    pyu2f:                         0.1.5-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    pyyaml:                        5.4.1-py39h3811e60_1       conda-forge
    ratelimiter:                   1.2.0-py_1002              conda-forge
    readline:                      8.1-h46c0cb4_0             conda-forge
    requests:                      2.26.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    rsa:                           4.7.2-pyh44b312d_0         conda-forge
    s3transfer:                    0.5.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    setuptools:                    57.4.0-py39hf3d152e_0      conda-forge
    simplejson:                    3.17.4-py39h3811e60_0      conda-forge
    six:                           1.16.0-pyh6c4a22f_0        conda-forge
    slacker:                       0.14.0-py_0                conda-forge
    smart_open:                    5.2.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    smmap:                         3.0.5-pyh44b312d_0         conda-forge
    snakemake:                     6.7.0-hdfd78af_0           bioconda   
    snakemake-minimal:             6.7.0-pyhdfd78af_0         bioconda   
    sqlite:                        3.36.0-h9cd32fc_0          conda-forge
    stopit:                        1.1.2-py_0                 conda-forge
    tabulate:                      0.8.9-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    tk:                            8.6.11-h21135ba_0          conda-forge
    toml:                          0.10.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    toposort:                      1.6-pyhd8ed1ab_0           conda-forge
    traitlets:                     5.0.5-py_0                 conda-forge
    typing-extensions:             3.10.0.0-hd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    typing_extensions:             3.10.0.0-pyha770c72_0      conda-forge
    ubiquerg:                      0.6.1-pyh9f0ad1d_0         conda-forge
    uritemplate:                   3.0.1-py_0                 conda-forge
    urllib3:                       1.26.6-pyhd8ed1ab_0        conda-forge
    veracitools:                   0.1.3-py_0                 conda-forge
    wcwidth:                       0.2.5-pyh9f0ad1d_2         conda-forge
    wheel:                         0.37.0-pyhd8ed1ab_1        conda-forge
    wrapt:                         1.12.1-py39h3811e60_3      conda-forge
    xmlrunner:                     1.7.7-py_0                 conda-forge
    xorg-libsm:                    1.2.3-hd9c2040_1000        conda-forge
    xorg-libx11:                   1.7.2-h7f98852_0           conda-forge
    xorg-libxext:                  1.3.4-h7f98852_1           conda-forge
    xorg-libxrender:               0.9.10-h7f98852_1003       conda-forge
    xorg-libxt:                    1.2.1-h7f98852_2           conda-forge
    yarl:                          1.5.1-py39h07f9747_0       conda-forge
    zipp:                          3.5.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0         conda-forge
    zstd:                          1.5.0-ha95c52a_0           conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

simplejson-3.1 100% |##################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00 363.11 kB/s
imagemagick-7. 100% |##################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00  12.48 MB/s
```

and right now it has been hung up on that step for 30 minutes. Sometimes it seems to get to the end of the list before hanging/failing like this. I have waited 30 minutes before and gotten no results and have resorted to killing the terminal. This was not a problem before last month but has gotten steadily worse to the point of failure.

Is there a way to check why this is happening/A way to look at the subprocesses that are being executed? As a scientist I am still a relative novice on command line tools.

Alternatively, is there a cleanup command I can run to make it faster? I am genuinely perplexed why it takes so long.

Comment: I'd first check the process status with `top` - could be the I/O bandwidth is getting saturated, which isn't uncommon on shared HPC systems. If your process is stuck in `D` state, then it's not really something we can help with (you'd need to talk to your sys admin(s)). Otherwise, maybe try throwing some verbosity args (`-v`: 1 for INFO, 2 for DEBUG, 3 for TRACE) into the install command, to see if it is hanging at any particular packages.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can try.  And one of these things will change your conda-life if you're not using it already.

Simple one first:  there is a clean command you should run every so often. `conda clean -h` for more info.  I generally just run `conda clean --all --yes` every now and again.

Game Changer: use mamba in place of conda*(really more as a supplement).  Mamba(https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba) is a re-write of conda in C.  If you have gotten used to conda build times, mamba is going to blow you away.  It works like so:

1: you install mamba into your conda base (generally its frowned upon to install anything into the conda base, but this is an exception-- Snakemake even publicly encourages it's use).

`conda install mamba -n base -c conda-forge`

And now, moving ahead, anyplace you would use 'conda' you use 'mamba', and get rewarded with some of you life back not waiting on conda :-)  --- there is one exception.  You still need the  base conda install && to activate environments you still specify conda activate and conda deactivate.  And best of all, it's no problem if you mistakenly (or intentionally) use conda and mamba interchangeably-- I don't think you'll want to however.